# How to run php files after upgrading OS X Yosemite to El Capitan?

Tags: php, macos, apache, upgrade

I've recently upgraded my OS X to El Capitan. Then created a php file inside my local server. The newly created file is displayed without error, but previous files in the same directory shows the PHP code in the browser. Also, I cannot access `phpmyadmin`, it shows `Forbidden` `You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.`

I have run `ls -l` to see the file permissions in the folder I am working on, everything seems ok. I don't see any change from previous files to the new file I have created. How can I fix this?

Comment: BTW, this question does not belong here, it might be a duplicate on OS coummunity.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading El Capitan would reset your apache config.
You need to change that enable all modules requires in your case **mod_alias**.

Comment: Can you give me a link which explains in details?

Comment: Look for how to enable mods in apache on mac